# React Github page not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages, github-api

[image]

I have create created a react app for ticket management and for connect with backend i have defined proxy in package.json as shown in the figure. this is finely working in local host. when i publish to github page, it not able to connect to backend and get 404 error since the proxy in package.json is not considering now. So how i define a proxy as like in the packag.json to github page i have hosted

github ripo: https://github.com/pranavmappoli/supportdesk

hosted page: https://pranavmappoli.github.io/supportdesk/

backend URL: https://pranavhelpdesk.herokuapp.com/

how could i resolve this issue other than putting the path in .env file

Comment: Are you sure you want to have your .env file public? You have your mongo url public and everyone can see it

Comment: add `.gitignore` file and put `.env` inside

Answer (score 1):

The webpack proxy is designed to be used as a hack during development.

In production you are supposed to configure CORS on the API or deploy the app to the same *origin* as it so you don't need a proxy.

An an alternative (not one I'd recommend) you could build a production ready proxy. If you do that then it will need to support CORS and **cannot be hosted on Github pages** which only support statics files.